# when using js in ie, className doesn't work in certain code. is anyone knows the why?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, classname

```
function openBBS() {
    var boardLinker = document.getElementsByClassName('boardLinker');
    for(i = 0 ; i < boardLinker.length+3 ; i++) {
        var allBoards = boardLinker.item('i');
        allBoards.className = "boardLinker_b";}}
```

I think this problem is being happening to not only me, there are a lot of peoples suffering from similar problem with me.

is there anyone who knows the why this problems happening in only ie, and what is the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quotation marks around your `i` variable within your `for` loop. Change:

```
var allBoards = boardLinker.item('i');
```

To:

```
var allBoards = boardLinker.item(i);
```